# iMac install Java, webpage test succeeds, `javac` fails

Tags: install, java

I'm trying to install Java on my iMac running 10.9.5. I downloaded and installed JDK according to the official Oracle instructions. When testing via the web-page at the end of the install, Java is detected. However, when running `javac` or `java` in the terminal, I get an error reporting I must install a JDK. I understand that there are different Javas for web apps and desktop apps, but why can only Safari detect my Java? Is there another way to install Java that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed a JRE instead of the JDK. The JDK can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).